# HANA: why does timestamp column truncate milliseconds and include timezone?

Tags: hana

I am working with HANA DB and I am confused why milliseconds are truncating from a timestamp column.

Here is my table create statement:

```
create table test (
  timestamp TIMESTAMP  NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

The values in the timestamp column follow this format:

```
Wed Oct31 2018 06:24:42 GMT+0000(UTC)
```

I would like to have a precision of at least 3 millisecond intervals

Thanks for your time in advance

Answer (score 1):

The SAP HANA timestamp data type supports up to 7 fractional second digits. It does not, however, store any information about the timezone.

The printout that you posted has been rendered by some SAP HANA client program. 
This client program renders the format of the timestamp (in HANA it really is just a number). As it appears, this client does not render fractional seconds but adds timezone information (apparently defaulting to UTC).

You can avoid the default rendering of date/time columns by converting the timestamp data to a text representation of your liking.

```
SELECT "timestamp"
     , "name"
     , to_nvarchar("timestamp", 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS:FF3') as "timestamp_as_TEXT"
FROM "test";
```

should display the timestamp including fractional seconds.

The whole topic of timestamp format conversion can get rather involved.

In case your DB client happens to be SAP HANA Studio, you may want to check this [blog post](http://lbreddemann.org/community-criss-cross-puzzle-posting-in-multiple-locales/) about how the LOCALE of your OS session influences the formatting. This [other post](http://lbreddemann.org/trouble-with-time/) gets more into details on timezone handling.